# Convert C# Function to calculate total number of weeks to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following function that calculates total weeks based on the `BillingStartDate` and `BillingEndDate`. This is calculated in a C# program, but I am creating a SQL query and would like this value calculated as well.

This is the C# function :

```
 private void calculateTotalWeeks()
 {
        if (!((dtpBillEnd.ValueIsDbNull) || (dtpBillStart.ValueIsDbNull)))
        {
            if (((DateTime)dtpBillEnd.Value).CompareTo((DateTime)dtpBillStart.Value) < 0)
            {
                lblTotalWeeks.Text = "Invalid End Date";
            }
            else
            {
                TimeSpan ts = ((DateTime)dtpBillEnd.Value).AddDays(1) - (DateTime)dtpBillStart.Value;
                lblTotalWeeks.Text = ((Double)ts.TotalDays / 7.0).ToString("0.0");

                if (Int32.Parse(lblTotalWeeks.Text.Substring(lblTotalWeeks.Text.Length - 1, 1)) % 2 != 0)
                {
                    string strBase = lblTotalWeeks.Text.Substring(0, lblTotalWeeks.Text.Length - 1);
                    lblTotalWeeks.Text = strBase + (Int32.Parse(lblTotalWeeks.Text.Substring(lblTotalWeeks.Text.Length - 1, 1)) - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what I think the equivalent would be in T-SQL:

```
(DATEDIFF(D, d.BillingStartDate, DATEADD(D, 1, d.BillingEndDate)) / 7.0)
```

This works for most part however for some where for example its 26.0 days between start and end date it displays 3.71 instead of 3.6.

Help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: 26/7 = 3.71. Why are you expecting 3.6?

Comment: because that is what the C# code is returning.  The question really is, why do these two functions return different numbers.

Comment: Because the C# function is outputting 3.6, where as the sql is outputting 3.71. I want to get the same result as in c#. WOuld this be the equivalent of that: ((DATEDIFF(D,DATEADD(D,1.d.BillingStartDate,d.BillingEndDate))/7.0)

Comment: The only reason the C# is outputting 3.6 is because of the extra logic within the `if` statement. The original `lblTotalWeeks.Text = ((Double)ts.TotalDays / 7.0).ToString("0.0");` line does indeed produce `3.7`, and would produce `3.71` if you change the string format to `"0.00"`.

Comment: Yeah as @goric says the "00" specifier causes the value to be rounded to the nearest digit preceding the decimal. Formatting 3.714 with "0.0" would result in the value 3.7.

Comment: FWIW, I highly recommend you rewrite that C# code to not keep jumping back and forth between decimal, text and int.  Figure out what you need as a decimal, and when you're done, format it and put in the text.  The way it is written now would be very difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the end-result to be **3 weeks and 5 days**, then you can make use of the following query:

```
SELECT      Convert(nvarchar, DATEDIFF(D, @BillingStartDate, @BillingEndDate) /7, 20) + ' weeks and' +
            Convert(nvarchar, DATEDIFF(D, @BillingStartDate, @BillingEndDate) %7, 20) + ' days'
```

This will give you a result of

```
3 weeks and 5 days
```

if the date difference is 26 days.

Instead, if you want the end-result to be **3.5 weeks**, then you can make use of the following query:

```
SELECT      Convert(nvarchar, DATEDIFF(D, @BillingStartDate, @BillingEndDate) /7, 20) + '.' + Convert(nvarchar, DATEDIFF(D, @BillingStartDate, @BillingEndDate) %7, 20) + ' weeks'
```

This will give you a result of

```
3.5 weeks
```

if the date difference is 26 days.

**EDIT:**

Also, modify your C# code here:

```
lblTotalWeeks.Text = ((Double)ts.TotalDays / 7.0).ToString("0.0");
```

should be

```
lblTotalWeeks.Text = Convert.ToString((Double)ts.TotalDays / 7.0));
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Check the edited answer. This is tested so will work as stated in the answer.